# jaxws wsdl common entities

Tags: web-services, wsdl, jaxb2, jax-ws-customization

I want to customize package name of entities used on a webservice. The main objective is to share entities between differents webservice.

I am using jaxws + jaxb to bind entities to their corresponding package.
However, only the ObjectFactory link to the entity is working. It seems that I can't override the use of the wsdl:definition:@targetnamespace for package name.

Here is an example:

I've got a FooBarRemoteService retourning two entities: Foo and Bar. Each of them are @XmlRootElement annotated with a namespace defined (Foo:com.test.foo, Bar:com.test.bar).

Here is the wsdl:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="FooBarRemoteService" targetNamespace="com.test.foobar" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="com.test.foobar" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http">
   <wsdl:types>
      <xs:schema elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="com.test.foobar" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns2="com.test.bar" xmlns:ns1="com.test.foo">
         <xs:import namespace="com.test.foo"/>
         <xs:import namespace="com.test.bar"/>
         <xs:element name="getBar" type="tns:getBar"/>
         <xs:element name="getBarResponse" type="tns:getBarResponse"/>
         <xs:element name="getFoo" type="tns:getFoo"/>
         <xs:element name="getFooResponse" type="tns:getFooResponse"/>
         <xs:complexType name="getFoo">
            <xs:sequence/>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:complexType name="getFooResponse">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:foo"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:complexType name="foo">
            <xs:sequence/>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:complexType name="getBar">
            <xs:sequence/>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:complexType name="getBarResponse">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:bar"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:complexType name="bar">
            <xs:sequence/>
         </xs:complexType>
      </xs:schema>
      <xs:schema targetNamespace="com.test.foo" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="com.test.foobar">
         <xs:import namespace="com.test.foobar"/>
         <xs:element name="foo" type="ns1:foo"/>
      </xs:schema>
      <xs:schema targetNamespace="com.test.bar" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="com.test.foobar">
         <xs:import namespace="com.test.foobar"/>
         <xs:element name="bar" type="ns1:bar"/>
      </xs:schema>
   </wsdl:types>
   <wsdl:message name="getFooResponse">
      <wsdl:part element="tns:getFooResponse" name="parameters"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="getFoo">
      <wsdl:part element="tns:getFoo" name="parameters"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="getBarResponse">
      <wsdl:part element="tns:getBarResponse" name="parameters"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="getBar">
      <wsdl:part element="tns:getBar" name="parameters"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:portType name="InterfaceFooBar">
      <wsdl:operation name="getFoo">
         <wsdl:input message="tns:getFoo" name="getFoo"/>
         <wsdl:output message="tns:getFooResponse" name="getFooResponse"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
      <wsdl:operation name="getBar">
         <wsdl:input message="tns:getBar" name="getBar"/>
         <wsdl:output message="tns:getBarResponse" name="getBarResponse"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="FooBarRemoteServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:InterfaceFooBar">
      <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="getFoo">
         <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
         <wsdl:input name="getFoo">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output name="getFooResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
      <wsdl:operation name="getBar">
         <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
         <wsdl:input name="getBar">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output name="getBarResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="FooBarRemoteService">
      <wsdl:port binding="tns:FooBarRemoteServiceSoapBinding" name="FooBar">
         <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/poc/FooBarRemoteService"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Here is the binding file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxws:bindings version="2.1"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
    <jaxb:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='com.test.foo']">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="subpackage.foo" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='com.test.bar']">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="subpackage.bar" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

Here is the command to generate java object files:

```
wsimport ../FooBar.wsdl -b ../binding.xml -verbose
```

And here are the generated files:

```
.
|-- foobar
|   `-- test
|       `-- com
|           |-- Bar.class
|           |-- FooBarRemoteService.class
|           |-- Foo.class
|           |-- GetBar.class
|           |-- GetBarResponse.class
|           |-- GetFoo.class
|           |-- GetFooResponse.class
|           |-- InterfaceFooBar.class
|           |-- ObjectFactory.class
|           `-- package-info.class
`-- subpackage
    |-- bar
    |   `-- ObjectFactory.class
    `-- foo
        `-- ObjectFactory.class
```

Destination folders are well renamed to subpackage folder. So the binding is taken in account however only ObjectFactory is present. Is their a way to have ObjectFactory with entity depending on it ?

My WSDL was generated with a simple program under wildfly:
Here are my files:

InterfaceFooBar

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "com.test.foobar")
public interface InterfaceFooBar {    
    @WebMethod
    public Bar getBar();
    @WebMethod
    public Foo getFoo();
}
```

FooBarRemoteService

```
@WebService(serviceName = "FooBarRemoteService",
    portName = "FooBar",
    name = "FooBar",
    endpointInterface = "poc.interfaces.helloworld.ws.InterfaceFooBar",
    targetNamespace = "com.test.foobar")
public class FooBar implements InterfaceFooBar {
    @Override
    public Bar getBar() {
        return new Bar();
    }
    @Override
    public Foo getFoo() {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

Bar

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "com.test.bar")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Bar {
}
```

Foo

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "com.test.foo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {
}
```

Thanks by your response.

Regards,

Damien

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I just found the response...

Just change the declaration of Foo and Bar by using @XmlType instead of @XmlRootElement and it is working ...

```
.
|-- foobar
|   `-- test
|       `-- com
|           |-- FooBarRemoteService.class
|           |-- GetBar.class
|           |-- GetBarResponse.class
|           |-- GetFoo.class
|           |-- GetFooResponse.class
|           |-- InterfaceFooBar.class
|           |-- ObjectFactory.class
|           `-- package-info.class
`-- subpackage
    |-- bar
    |   |-- Bar.class
    |   |-- ObjectFactory.class
    |   `-- package-info.class
    `-- foo
        |-- Foo.class
        |-- ObjectFactory.class
        `-- package-info.class
```

Damned I spend one day on this :(